# 10-fold CV on cubic spline regression without using cv.glm()

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to apply 10-fold CV on cubic spline regression without using cv.glm(). Data used is `wage~age` in Wage dataset from ISLR library. I would like to test the degree of freedom from 1 to 8. However the CV MSEs and standard errors have very small differences as shown in the output. I am not really sure if this is alright so I would like some opinions on my workings. Thank you!

```
rm(list=ls())
library(splines)
library(ISLR)
attach(Wage)
Wage<- na.omit(Wage)
tr= sample(1:nrow(Wage), nrow(Wage)/2)
te= (-tr)
Wagetr= Wage[tr,]
# Tuning parameter= the bins, suggest some possible values
number_of_bins = seq(1,8)
k = 10
folds = sample( 1:k, nrow(Wagetr), replace=TRUE ) 
cv.errors = matrix( NA, k, length(number_of_bins) )

for( i in 1:length(number_of_bins)){ # for each number of knots to test
  
  for( j in 1:k ){ # for each fold
    cubicfit = glm( wage ~ bs( age, df=i), data=Wagetr[folds!=j,] )
    cubicpred = predict( cubicfit, newdata=Wagetr[folds==j,] )
    cv.errors[j,i] = mean( ( Wagetr[folds==j,]$wage - cubicpred )^2 ) }
  
}

cv.errors.mean = apply(cv.errors,2,mean)
cv.errors.stderr = apply(cv.errors,2,sd)/sqrt(k)

min.cv.index = which.min( cv.errors.mean )
one_se_up_value = ( cv.errors.mean+cv.errors.stderr )[min.cv.index] 

# Set up the x-y limits for plotting:
min_lim=min( one_se_up_value, cv.errors.mean, cv.errors.mean-cv.errors.stderr, cv.errors.mean+cv.errors.stderr ) * 0.9
max_lim=max( one_se_up_value, cv.errors.mean, cv.errors.mean-cv.errors.stderr, cv.errors.mean+cv.errors.stderr ) * 1.1

plot( number_of_bins, cv.errors.mean, ylim=c(min_lim,max_lim), pch=19, type='b', xlab='number of cut bins', ylab='CV estimate of the prediction error' )
lines( number_of_bins, cv.errors.mean-cv.errors.stderr, lty='dashed' )
lines( number_of_bins, cv.errors.mean+cv.errors.stderr, lty='dashed' )
abline( h=one_se_up_value, col='red' )

# Fit the optimal model using all data:
# 
nob = 4
fit = glm( wage ~ bs( age, df=nob), data= Wage)

Wagete= Wage[te,]
plot( Wagete$age, Wagete$wage )
aRng = range(Wagete$age)

Xage= seq( from=aRng[1], to=aRng[2], length.out=100 )
Ywage= predict( fit, newdata=list( age=a_predict ) )
lines( Xage, Ywage, col='red', lw=4 )
```

Output:

```
> cv.errors.mean
[1] 1528.594 1528.594 1528.594 1522.770 1527.669 1532.042 1534.248
[8] 1539.894

> cv.errors.stderr
[1] 109.2536 109.2536 109.2536 107.4087 108.8886 109.4759 109.9675
[8] 111.3593
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you set up folds gives you folds with roughly equal sizes but i guess it's ok:

```
folds = sample( 1:k, nrow(Wagetr), replace=TRUE )
```

You can try:

```
folds = sample((1:nrow(Wagetr) %% k))+1
```

We can look at the fit and data:

```
COLS = c("#FF6F00FF","#C71000FF","#008EA0FF","#8A4198FF","#5A9599FF","#FF6348FF")

with(Wagetr,plot(age,wage))

for(i in 3:8){
cubicfit = glm( wage ~ bs( age, df=i), data=Wagetr)

lines(seq(20,80,by=2),predict(cubicfit,data.frame(age=seq(20,80,by=2))),col = COLS[i-2])

}
legend("topright",fill=COLS,paste0("df=",3:8))
```

[image]

The degree of freedom for splines decides how to bin your independent variable to construct the respective polynomials in each interval. If you agree with me, you can just fit a cubic fit over the whole data? Basically there is no where in the data where you expect a "twist" that requires a knot.